how to Displaying Shapefile
I have a file in tif format. Now I want to show the border of the basin area using the shape file. but i can't. Can anyone guide me?
I want to put the shape file of the main basin of Iran on the map of Iran in TIF format.
from pyidw import idw
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.colors import Normalize

fig, ax, cbar = idw.show_map(
input_raster="Anomaly (2051-2075)_SSP126.tif",
colormap="brg",
image_size=1.5,
return_figure=True)

image = ax.get_images()[0]
image.set_clim(10, -7)
cbar.update_normal(image)

ax.set_title("Maximum temperature map")
ax.set_xlabel("Longitude")
ax.set_ylabel("Latitude")
plt.show()

